# Как решить проблему «нам не удалось создать новый или найти существующий раздел при установке виндовс»?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Есть жесткий диск на 150 гб. Поэксперементировал в убунту в gparted, создав два раздела: один с ext4, другой с ntfs.

Потом решил объединить разделы в один основной и задал файловую систему ntfs.

Теперь пытаюсь установить виндовс и пишет ошибку из шапке.
Нашел решение на этом сайте виндовс
Пытался использовать diskpart, сделал все как в статье, но без результатно.

Может подкинете идею,
Заранее благодарен

Comment: Удалите все разделы. Если не поможет - затрите нулями первые сектора.

Comment: только что установил убунту на этот диск, из него и пишу. Сейчас попробую установить виндовс

Answer (score 0):

После установки на этот же диск убунту, в установщике виндовс очистил все разделы, получился один пустой, и на наконец-то стало устанавливаться виндовс.
Наверное, можно было решить другим быстрым способом, но я